# how to post on facebook timeline using django 1.8?

Tags: django-1.8

```
token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token
graph = GraphAPI(token)
profile_id = request.facebook.user.facebook_id
```

How do I implement this is django 1.8?

Comment: In django 1.8 I am having trouble using GraphAPI. Is there any alternative to that?